# Bash script running correctly in Linux machine but not when executed via Jenkins from a Windows machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, ant

I have a Bash script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR_A=$(echo "cat //artifact/fileName" |  xmllint --shell BuildResult.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $3}')
echo $VAR_A
```

I have Jenkins installed on a Windows machine and via Cygwin openssh, I am connecting to the Suse Linux machine in which this script is residing.

When I call the above script via an ANT sshexec command configured in Jenkins, it is running OK but no output.

On the other hand, when I am running the same script from within the SUSE Linux system, it is echoing current result.

I am not able to figure the root cause and respective fix. I have checked the shell in Suse Linux and it is set to /bin/bash system wide.

Comment: I suggest to add full path to file BuildResult.xml.

Comment: Tried with full path to BuildResult.xml. However, no success. Still blank output, when executed via jenkins.

Comment: I suggest to add full path to xmllint, sed, tr and awk, too.

Comment: Tried with full path to the above mentioned. No success:(!!!

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Added set -x/set +x and this is the output on Jenkins console-   [sshexec] 222: echo 'cat //artifact/fileName'
  [sshexec] 222: /usr/bin/sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
  [sshexec] 222: /usr/bin/sed '/^\/ >/d'
  [sshexec] 222: /usr/bin/tr -d '\n'
  [sshexec] 222: /usr/bin/xmllint --shell /tmp/Deploy/BuildResult.xml
  [sshexec] 222: /usr/bin/awk -F------- '{print $3}'
  [sshexec] 
  [sshexec] 22: VAR_Wfc=
  [sshexec] 22: echo
  
Still, I am unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: Please refrain [from urgent begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) in questions, thanks.

Comment: Sure...Since, it is indeed an urgent requirement, I stated it in my post. I am  stuck because of this issue:(.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? whatever it is a bash script is likely not your best tool - and using regular expressions to parse an xml file is always the wrong path.

Comment: What I am trying to do can be find in my post: Shell script to fetch value of a node appearing multiple times in an XML. Please see and suggest me.